# Validating expression using 2 Generic Stacks

Tags: java

The task is to implement a generic stack (can not use the libraries from java), make the user input an expression using true and false for booleans b1 and b2, logical operators (and, or, not, iff, implies) recognize if its boolean or operator and send to 2 stacks, then poping the stacks to evaluate if its a valid expression, i.e: input:(b1 and b2) implies b3 is a valid expression but B3 and (b2 or) is not, I have issues with the stack part, since the peek is not returning any element, here is my code so far, note: the charat is because I would be checking that the brackets are balanced as well:

```
public class MyStack<T> {

    class StackOverFlowException extends RuntimeException{}
    class EmptyStackException extends RuntimeException{}
    
    private T[] stack;
    private int top;
    
    public MyStack(int size) {
        this.stack = (T[]) new Object[size];
        this.top = 0;   
        
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.top == 0;
    }
    
    public boolean isFull() {
        return this.top == stack.length;
    }
    
    public void push(T x) {
        if(top == stack.length) {
            throw new StackOverFlowException();
        }
        else {
            this.stack[top] = x;
            top++;
        }
    }
    
    public T pop() {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        else {
            T value = this.stack[--top];
            return value;
        }
    }
    
    public T peek() {
        return this.stack[top];
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyStack<String> tf = new MyStack(100);
        MyStack<String> operators = new MyStack(100);
        
        System.out.println("Please input the expression to evaluate: ");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);   
        String expression = scn.nextLine();
        String tokens[] = expression.split(" ");
        int n = tokens.length;
        boolean P1 = true;
        boolean P2 = true;
        boolean result = true;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        
            String separate = tokens[i];
            char x = separate.charAt(i);
            if(tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("true")||tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                tf.push(separate);
                tf.peek();

            }
            else if(tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("and")||tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("not")||tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("or")||tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("implies")||tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase("iff")) {
                operators.push(separate);
            }
            
            else {
                System.out.println("Expression not Valid!");
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "I have issues with the stack part"?

Comment: when peeking to see the top returns null, im trying to see if the elements are indeed going into the stacks

Comment: Isn't `top` always 1 more than the index of the actual top element?

Answer (score 0):

The `top` variable is being misinterpreted in the `peek()` method (as well as the `isEmpty()` method).

As implemented, `top` is a misnomer since it is actually the size of the stack (which may also be considered the index for the *next* element to be pushed).  So your `peek()` method should be looking at the element *before* `top`.

Alternatively, you may to define `top` as the element at the top of the stack, as this is generally how you are using it elsewhere.  In this case, you will need to define a flag value to indicate the stack is empty.

In any case, you need handle the empty Stack case in the `peek()` method.

```
public class MyStack {
  private static final int EMPTY = -1;
  private int top = EMPTY;

  ... other stuff ...

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return EMPTY == top;
  }
  public T peek() {
    if (ifEmpty()) {
       throw new EmptyStackException("Cannot peek into empty Stack");
    }
    return stack[top];
  }
}
```